# How do I target placed blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am mildly experienced with commands. I was hoping to target an actual set block. I think it'll probably be done with the `/execute` command, as I came up with this command:

```
/execute @e[type=!Player] ~ ~ ~ summon LightningBolt ~ ~ ~
```

I appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, an actual set block? If you want to summon a lightning bolt on for example X:123 Y:456 Z:789 you can just use `summon LightningBolt 123 456 789`

Comment: I was hoping to build a detector. It's supposed to summon a lightning bolt at a command block. When I posted this I was explaining that it might have something to do with the execute command. I was telling that I knew how to make a tesla. But the Skylinerw changed it

Comment: I also wanted to know if you could summon an armor stand relative to say, a gold block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only target a specific block by having an entity close by or if you have the coordinates. If the area in which it may be isn't too big, you could summon an armorstand that travels across in a straight line, with `execute` and `detect`. If it should happen whenever an entity stands on a gold block you could do:

`execute @e ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ gold_block 0 summon LightningBolt`